# How to customize exisiting module with new menuitem and actions via new module in odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

customization of exisiting module with new menuitem and actions via new module in odoo

Two modules - Module A (existing) and Module B (new module).
Using Module B extending (adding) New Menuitems (menu) and new Views with their actions into Module A.

I get this error :
""External ID not found in the system: module B.action_open_view""

here is my code of Module B:

```
<menuitem id="menu_website" name="Website" parent="menu_settings_websites"   sequence="10" action="action_open_view"/>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_open_view">
                <field name="name">Websites</field>
                <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
                <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
                 <field name="help" type="html">
                 <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click Here</p>
                    <p>Manage Websites.</p>

                </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: If you want to refer to an xml od in module A you need to give the full XML_ID.   `ModuleA.action_open_view`

Answer (score 1):

Just rearrange the `menuitem` and `action` definitions.

```xml
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_open_view">
            <field name="name">Websites</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
             <field name="help" type="html">
             <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click Here</p>
                <p>Manage Websites.</p>

            </field>
    </record>

<menuitem id="menu_website" name="Website" parent="menu_settings_websites"   sequence="10" action="action_open_view"/>
```

You trying to invoke an `action` before it creates. You need to define it first and then call it.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Now i modified code and placed menu items under each files where actions exist so now its working.. Thanks for your kind guiding me ..